# AWS MSK working with shell command but not with python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, aws-msk

I created a AWS MSK instance with two brokers. I can use that to produce and consume messages by using kafka#s shell commands (`kafka-console-producer.sh` and `kafka-console-consumer.sh`) but the problem is, it is not working with [kafka python](https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/) library.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
      bootstrap_servers=["address_of_broker_1:9092","address_of_broker_1:9092"],
      auto_offset_reset='latest',
      enable_auto_commit=True,
      api_version=(2,0,2),
      group_id='group8',
 fetch_max_wait_ms=5)
consumer.subscribe(['test1'])

for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)
```

This does not work because,

```
sudo sh kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server address_of_broker1:9092,address_of_broker2:9092 --list --all-groups
```

this only show 2 default consumer

```
amazon.msk.canary.group.broker-1
amazon.msk.canary.group.broker-2
```

whereas, when I use `kafka-console-consumer.sh` is show a newly added consumer in the list.

Problem is, the python code does not show any error message. Which is why I am completely clueless.

Can anybody give me a clue what might be happening or where can I see the error log in AWS MSK

Comment: Typo? Your Python code says 9022, not 9092 like your shell commands

Comment: ah, sorry, but i does not working either

Comment: Does `test1` topic actually have data being produced to it? You're going to get no group until offsets are actually committed. Since you're starting at the end of a topic, then if there's no data, nothing needs to be committed

Comment: found the problem. I was running the python code from my local network and to be connected  the code need to be run within the same vpc. It works if I run form my EC2 which is in the same vpc of msk

Comment: Or you could open up the VPC firewall to allow traffic from your address

Comment: You can turn on debugging to get details on the msk connection. Configure logging via import logging logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) (surround name with two "_") SO is removing them.)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)